# Create link to related tables in SQLAlchemy Declarative

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask with SQLAlchemy and Declarative, but am new to it. And I have a Parent- and a Child-Tabele/Class.

In my database there are thousands of parents. And so far everything is working, but the two tables do not link nicely for the user.

I'd like to **provide a link in the parent to create** (and eventually also update) **a child**, without the user having to find the parents id again in the very long list.

I've studied the [documentation of Declarative](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html) already, but found no hint how to bring this to work.

- Is there an (easy) way to link between related classes? (I don't want to display data from the other class, I want to create a new/update an existing entry.)
- If not possible, how can I predefine some values already in a link (e.g. the id) while creating a new entry?

My code so far is:

```
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)
```

and:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship('Child', backref='child')
```

Answer (score 1):

When I understand your question correctly you can do the following:

Define a field in your Child Class:

```
criterias = relationship('Criteria', secondary=criteria_controls, backref=backref('criteria', lazy='dynamic'))
```

See the [Backref documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#linking-relationships-with-backref) for more help

Let me know if this helps.
Maybe you can provide an example parent-child relation of yours?

cheers

Edit:

I see now that I didn't fully get to you with my answer. Maybe it is simpler than you think.
I am still not quite sure what you want to acomplish, but you can create a new child simply by doing this:

```
p = Parent()
p.child = Child()
db.add(p)
db.commit()
```

you should be able to directly access the child object by the child field.

to verify try this:

```
print(type(p.child))
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't manage to add a "Create new Child"-Link to my parent table with this. There is the child displayed, but that was not my problem. (I've also clarified my question.)